# Check if user is in a forest using location

Tags: android, google-maps, google-places-api

I would like to write an app that can tell if a user is in a forest or not. 
Is there a way to do that using android?

What I tried:

1. Used Google's Places API and hoped to get the place type "natural_feature" whenever the user is in a forest. Unfortunately I get "ZERO_RESULTS" most of the time
2. Read about WMS Layers that show forest areas and tried to put one on top of a GoogleMap. Did not get it to work and also noticed that I would most likely only be able to show the map not check if the user is in one of the areas of the layer...

Is there a way to check if the current position is in a green area on google maps? That might even be enough if everything else fails.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Dunno if possible, just an idea: google maps has forest as "green area" (i mean the color of the map where forests are). Can you inspect the color of the map in the position the user is?

Comment: I'll definitely check it out!

Answer (score 1):

I am currently not aware if there is an easier method to do this but you could try the following:

1. Get a snapshot from your map
2. Get the average color of the snapshot
3. Compare the average color with your predefined forest color
4. If their difference is lower than your accepted tolerance then you are in a
   map green area

The result though might not be accurate if you are not zoom into the map and the green area is too small. In this case you could do your calculations only on specific zoom levels.

```
        final int forestR = 214;
        final int forestG = 233;
        final int forestB = 215;
        final int tolerance = 60;

        Button button = (Button) findViewById(R.id.check_forest_btn);
        button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                GoogleMap.SnapshotReadyCallback callback = new GoogleMap.SnapshotReadyCallback() {


                    @Override
                    public void onSnapshotReady(Bitmap snapshot) {
                        int pixelCount = 0;
                        int redColors = 0;
                        int greenColors = 0;
                        int blueColors = 0;
                        for (int y = 0; y < snapshot.getHeight(); y++) {
                            for (int x = 0; x < snapshot.getWidth(); x++) {
                                int c = snapshot.getPixel(x, y);
                                pixelCount++;
                                redColors += Color.red(c);
                                greenColors += Color.green(c);
                                blueColors += Color.blue(c);
                            }
                        }
                        // calculate average of bitmap r,g,b values
                        int red = (redColors / pixelCount);
                        int green = (greenColors / pixelCount);
                        int blue = (blueColors / pixelCount);

                        int difference = Math.abs(red - forestR) + Math.abs(green - forestG) + Math.abs(blue - forestB);

                        boolean isForest = difference < tolerance;//use this to display your information
                    }
                };

                map.snapshot(callback);
            }
        });
```